# List append in pandas cell

Tags: python, list, pandas, types, append

I have a dataframe  which contains list item in a column.

Example:
df:

```
column1, column2, column3
1         'c'       ['d']
2         'x'       []
3         'foo'     ['car']
```

so I want to append another item into column3

the result should be like this

```
column1, column2, column3
1         'c'       ['d','t']
2         'x'       ['t']
3         'foo'     ['car','t']
```

Currently I use the method like this

```
df['column3']=df['column3'].apply(lambda x: x.append('t'))
```

But the the column3 became

```
column1, column2, column3
1         'c'       none
2         'x'       none
3         'foo'     none
```

Wonder how to do that using apply function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use:

```
df['column3'] += ['t']
```

Instead of `apply`. The problem is `.append` works *in-place* and returns `None`

You of course could do something silly if you really wanted to use `.apply` + `lambda`:

```
df.column3.apply(lambda x: x.append('t') or x)
```

Comment: You win for 15 sec, nice solution :-)

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work with Pandas 1.x:
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
Or TypeError: Cannot broadcast np.ndarray with operand of type <class 'list'>
if you give [['t']].

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with `apply()`.  Use `+` instead of `append()`.

```
df.column3 = df.column3.apply(lambda x: x+['t'])
```