# How to add value to pandas cells consisting of list using pandas 1.X

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I used to run the following operation using pandas version 0.23.4. Now using pandas 1.3.3 (with Python 3.7) the last line raises "TypeError: Cannot broadcast np.ndarray with operand of type <class 'list'>". Any ideas how to accomplish such operations in the more recent pandas versions? Thanks in advance.

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df["example" ] = np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist()
df.loc[df.col2 == 4, "example"] += [str("A")] # This does no longer work in pandas 1.3.3
```

This question is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340518/list-append-in-pandas-cell), where however the answer to my question is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply()` instead:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df["example" ] = np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist()
df.loc[df.col2 == 4, "example"].apply(lambda x: x.append(str("A")))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    col1  col2 example
 0     1     3      []
 1     2     4     [A]
 2     3     4     [A]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works, although I hoped for a solution without lambda function .

Comment: I dont know if it is possible. Looks like the np.arrays does not have the same methos of a standard list. Take a look in this topic: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801707/broadcasting-function-calls-in-np-array)