# Pandas Dataframe add element to a list in a cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying something like this:
[List append in pandas cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340518/list-append-in-pandas-cell)

But the problem is the post is old and everything is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

```
d = {'col1': ['TEST', 'TEST'], 'col2': [[1, 2], [1, 2]], 'col3': [35, 89]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TEST | [1, 2, 3] | 35 |
| TEST | [1, 2, 3] | 89 |

My Dataframe looks like this, were there is the col2 is the one I am interested in. I need to add [0,0] to the lists in col2 for every row in the DataFrame. My real DataFrame is of dynamic shape so I cant just set every cell on its own.

End result should look like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TEST | [1, 2, 3, 0, 0] | 35 |
| TEST | [1, 2, 3, 0, 0] | 89 |

I fooled around with `df.apply` and `df.assign` but I can't seem to get it to work.
I tried:

```
df['col2'] += [0, 0]

df = df.col2.apply(lambda x: x.append([0,0]))
     Which returns a Series that looks nothing like i need it

df = df.assign(new_column = lambda x: x + list([0, 0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to go but, option 2 works with a little modification

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': ['TEST', 'TEST'], 'col2': [[1, 2], [1, 2]], 'col3': [35, 89]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df["col2"] = df["col2"].apply(lambda x: x + [0,0])
print(df)
```

Firstly, if you want to add all members of an iterable to a list use `.extend` instead of `.append`. This doesn't work because the method works inplace and doesn't return anything so "col2" values become `None`, so use list summation instead. Finally, you want to assign your modified column to the original DataFrame, not override it (this is the reason for the Series return)

Answer (score 0):

One idea is use list comprehension:

```
df["col2"] = [x + [0,0] for x in  df["col2"]]
   
print (df)
   col1          col2  col3
0  TEST  [1, 2, 0, 0]    35
1  TEST  [1, 2, 0, 0]    89
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for val in df['col2']:
    val.append(0)
```